# AWS Tools for Powershell, version differences

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have been testing an older AWS Tools install using `AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-3.3.398.0_ps-3.3.390.0_tk-1.14.4.1.msi` and a newer install using `AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-3.5.2.0_ps-4.1.0.0_tk-1.14.5.0.msi`. The code that I am using to test with is

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey:$ACCESSKEY -SecretKey:$SECRETKEY -StoreAs:default

$items = Get-S3Object -BucketName:$BUCKETNAME -Region:'eu-west-1' -Key:'revit/2020'
Write-Host "$($items.Length) items"

$count = 1
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Host "$count $($item.key)"
    $count ++
}
```

I am seeing VERY different behavior, and can't figure out why. With 3.3 the code works as intended, I end up with a list of files in my bucket and key. Performance is pretty decent, it takes a moment but I have about 5000 files in may "subfolders".
When I run this with 4.1 it takes 3-5 times as long and returns nothing.
It seems that Help is a bit different too. A first run of `get-help Get-S3Object -detailed` will take as long as 10 minutes to run, with CPU, Memory and Disk access often at 99% utilization. A second run is quite quick. 3.3 Does nothing of the sort.

So, is this current build of AWS Tools for Powershell just not ready for prime time? My searches for *AWS Tools 4.1 performance* have turned up nothing.
For what it is worth, I am using the MSI installer because I need the install to actually work consistently, and the NuGet approach has been very problematic on a number of production workstations. But if there is another option I would love to look at it. The main issue is I need ultimately to do the install and immediately load the modules and work with AWS. I don't have that working with the MSI based install yet, but that's for a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they changed the results from `Get-S3Object`. You will need to add `-Select S3Objects.Key` to get the results you're looking for (or just `-select *`). Here's the excerpt from the change notes:

> Most cmdlets have a new parameter: -Select. Select can be used to change the value returned by the cmdlet. For example the service API used by Get-S3Object returns a ListObjectsResponse object but the cmdlet is configured to return only the S3Objects field. Now you can specify -Select * to receive the full API response. You can also specify the path to a nested result property like -Select S3Objects.Key. In certain situations it may be useful to return a cmdlet parameter, this can be achieved with -Select ^ParameterName.

Found by going to [the Change Notes](https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and doing a CTRL+F for *Get-S3Object*. Hope this resolves it for you!

Comment: It never occurred to me that the change history would be on GitHub rather than the AWS web site. Still weird that none of my searching found anything, but book marked now. Now to figure out how to use the cmdlets immediately after installing.